# python: group a multidimensional list by column. The fastest way

Tags: python, list, grouping

having a list like

```
[
[name, title, amount, 'en', category],
[name, title, amount, 'en', category],
[name, title, amount, 'it', category],
[name, title, amount, 'it', category],
[name, title, amount, 'it', category],
[name, title, amount, 'es', category],
]
```

i would like to divide and group the list by language.
For example the list below will be

```
[
[name, title, amount, 'en', category],
[name, title, amount, 'en', category]
]

[
[name, title, amount, 'it', category],
[name, title, amount, 'it', category],
[name, title, amount, 'it', category]
]

[
[name, title, amount, 'es', category]
]
```

it doesn't matter if it will be a dictionary or a list or a tuple. i would like it to be fast.

Then for any grouped array by language i would like to group them the same way for category.
My problem is that i don't know in advance the different langs and categories, so i was considering to scan before the whole list to take note of all the different langs and categories and then use list comprehension for everyone of those. but i am pretty sure it's not an efficient method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this may helpful for you:

```
def getMap(data,index):
res = {}
for v in data:
    if(v[index] in res):
        res[v[index]].append(v)
    else:
        res[v[index]] = [v]
return res
print(getMap(a,3))
```